# FlexBox doesn't seem to work with the Image component of Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, image, next.js, flexbox

I have the following component called `Guitar` (image and its contents)

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../styles/Guitar.module.css'

const Guitarra = ({guitar}) => {
  console.log(guitar)
  const {url, published_at, name, image, id, desc, price} = guitar;
  return (
    <div className={styles.guitar}>
   
        <Image 
          priority='true'
          src={image.url}
          alt={`Image Guitar ${name}`}
          width={180}
          height={400}
          layout='responsive'
        />
    
      <div className={styles.text_content}>
        <h3 className={styles.title}>{name}</h3>
        <p className={styles.desc}>{desc}</p>
        <p className={styles.price}>{`${price} €`}</p>
        <Link href={`/guitar/${url}`}>
          <a className={styles.link}>
            See Product
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Guitar
```

What it receives for props is a whole json object coming from an API that I have created thanks to Strapi. For the styles I'm using the way Next.js recommends, customizable css modules.

The result of this code should be this design:

[image]

To create that structure I wanted to use flexbox in the guitar class, since it is easier, I leave the image to the left of the content, and I'm laying out the rest, but for some reason flexbox does not seem to work well with the  component of Next.js, it is not the first time that happens to me, when I want to apply flexbox the image disappears completely, I tried to put in a div the Image component, but does not solve the problem, finally if I use Grid, everything works correctly, is the strange thing about this, does anyone know why this error?

With these styles it works:

```
.guitar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Best Regard

Comment: I would wrap the `<Image />` component in another wrapper, which might create the single tree node `flex` needs.

Comment: For image components in next.js i will use global.css instead of css modules, it seems to do the trick

Comment: @AndyHoffman yes i tried to do that but same problem, doesn't work so.. i will use grid for that

Comment: I would love to test your code somewhere. Have a link?